# I don't know why can't I get "Hanja list" of ImmGetCandidateList() func

Tags: ime

I tried some code for getting a "Hanja List" of ImmGetCandidateList() in Korea os win7 and win10.

I'm making a game. and I need a Hanja List in the game.
When I run in Windows7, I can get Hanja List with using ImmGetCandidateList().
However, when I run in Windows10, I can't get HanjaList.

I don't know why it is.

code

```
DWORD dwBufLen = 0;
LPCANDIDATELIST pCandiList = (LPCANDIDATELIST)new CHAR[1024];
HHOOK gHook;

LRESULT CALLBACK WinHookCallBack(INT nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    CWPSTRUCT* lpWp = (CWPSTRUCT*)lParam;
    switch (lpWp->message)
    {
    case WM_IME_NOTIFY:
    {
        if (lpWp->wParam == IMN_OPENCANDIDATE)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        HIMC hImc = ImmGetContext(hWnd);
        memset(pCandiList, 0, sizeof(CHAR) * 1024);
        dwBufLen = ImmGetCandidateList(hImc, 0, pCandiList, 0);
        ImmReleaseContext(hWnd, hImc);
    }break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(gHook, nCode, lpWp->wParam, lpWp->lParam);
}

BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{

   hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable

   hWnd = CreateWindow(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

   HWND hWndEdit = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, TEXT("edit"), TEXT("test"), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 100, 20, 140, 20, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);

   gHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, WinHookCallBack,     GetModuleHandle(NULL), GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, NULL));

   HWND hWndIME = ImmGetDefaultIMEWnd(hWnd);
   ShowOwnedPopups(hWndIME, false);

   return TRUE;
}
```

I made a simple win32 project for IME test.
And I tried two way.

[focused outside of textfield](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYj5Q.jpg)

[focused textfiedl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjgR4.jpg)

When I focused outside of Textfield. dwBufLen is bigger than zero.
However, when I focused Textfield. dwBufLen is zero. with I can see default candidate window.

I think when default candidate window disables I can get a Hanja list.

How can I get a Hanja list when I focused Textfield.

I need a Hanja candidate list for use in MyProject.

Thank you for reading my post. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I integrated DxDsample's TSFsystem. It was working in Win10.

If anyone has the problem, try it.